# Laravel auth sometimes retrieve wrong user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have a problem in my laravel application, it is like a nightmare to me   i'v tried everything i know to solve it, but unfortunately i don't have enough luck for that, so i posted this question for you guys to guide me through this, the issue is the auth system sometimes retrieve the wrong user as a current user... I mean sometimes when I am working in the admin area and while i submit a form or refreshing the page the application shows a wrong auth user (not the one i've logged in with)...and sometimes it logging me out completely. 
I dont know what causes this, i've tried many theories but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Update :

My laravel version is 5.6.1 and i deployed the application on sitground servers.

I'm using file based session, and I am using multiple auth, one for regular users and the other for the admin, i also tried to sperate the users table into two deffrient tables one for regular users and the other for admin, however it didn't solve the problem.

I've registered the multiple auth as the following

Config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'admin',
    ],
],
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    'admin' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Admin::class,
    ],
],
```

Route file web route :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => [ 'auth:admin']], function()
{     

}
```

Comment: Your configuration seems ok to me, can you provide us additional details. Like how do you show the current user. What is your `view` looks like for admin;

Comment: I always use Auth::guard('admin') 
To get the current logged in user in the view, or in storing the id as a forign key

Comment: same here, i think it happent by session data.

Comment: @MarosdeeUma i tried to use database based session and the issue disappeared

Comment: @IbrahimMohamedAbdElhay I fixed by told to server owner to disable caching on server `X-Cache-Status: BYPASS`

Comment: Is there any other solution instead of disabling the cache?

Answer (score 0):

first of all create two middleware Admin and User

Route file web route

```
Route::group(array('middleware' => ['User']), function () 
{ 


}); 

Route::group(array('middleware' => ['Admin','User']), function () 
{ 


});
```

Comment: Hay Harry,
I already use two different route group and middleware for users and admin

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom middleware for this:

here is function:

```
     $USER = Session::get('USER');
     $ADMIN = Session::get('ADMIN');
     if($ADMIN || $USER) {
        return $next($request);
     }
```

Comment: I already use two deffrient route group and middleware to handle this